# How to rotate all objects of canvas at once using Fabric.js?

Tags: html, fabricjs

I am working on custom product designer which uses Fabric.js. I want to rotate all objects of canvas at once by pressing one button (rotate left, rotate right).

I have achieved this using this code :

```
stage.forEachObject(function(obj){
    obj.setAngle(rotation).setCoords();
  });
  stage.renderAll();
```

But it has one bug that every element rotates with its own center point. I want that every element rotates with respect to whole canvas element.

Answer (score 4):

Grouping and rotating the group did not work so well for me. Here is another solution based on [this js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darbs/WcMdW/1/).

```
rotateAllObjects (degrees) {

  let canvasCenter = new fabric.Point(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2) // center of canvas
  let radians = fabric.util.degreesToRadians(degrees)

  canvas.getObjects().forEach((obj) => {
      let objectOrigin = new fabric.Point(obj.left, obj.top)
      let new_loc = fabric.util.rotatePoint(objectOrigin, canvasCenter, radians)
      obj.top = new_loc.y
      obj.left = new_loc.x
      obj.angle += degrees //rotate each object buy the same angle
      obj.setCoords()
  });

  canvas.renderAll()
},
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add all the objects to a group an then rotate the group. This way you can also set the center for rotation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can you please share the code how to create group with all the objects on my canvas, as there can be any number of objects user can create.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it could be solved

```
function rotate(a) {
                var group = new fabric.Group(canvas.getObjects());

                //angle is var with scope out of this function, 
                //so you can use this function as rotate(90) and keep rotating
                angle = (angle + a) % 360;
                group.rotate(angle);

                canvas.centerObject(group);
                group.setCoords();
                canvas.renderAll();
}
```

Comment: new fabric group should have coordinates

Answer (score 0):

FabricJS rotate everything and maintain the relative position also.

[image]

[image]

You can download the files here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UV1nBdfBk6bg9SztyVoWyLJ4eEZJgZRf/view?usp=sharing